# How can I split my key so that one part is top right and the other part is top left?

Tags: gnuplot

since my last post I tried cleaning up my code a bit and am almost done with the plot. The only thing left to do is splitting the key of the first plot into two parts. One being the titles of the graphs and the other one being the time that data was captured. The title should go top left while the time should go top right.

The code:

```
set key top left title '0 s'´

set ylabel 'Konzentration'
set format y '%g'
set ytics border out nomirror 2
set mytics 2

plot 'data/paper_2_csv_a_0000.csv' using 3:1 axes x1y1 with lines ls 1 title 'Aktivator',\
     'data/paper_2_csv_h_0000.csv' using 3:1 axes x1y1 with lines ls 2 title 'Inhibitor'
;
```

produces the output

[image]

So how can I move the "Aktivator" and "Inhibitor" part to the left while leaving the "0 s" where it is right now?

Comment: Are you talking about the title of the legend (or key) or about the title of the whole plot? These are two different titles.

Comment: Excuse me, but don't quite understand the difference. I'm talking about the key and its content which is "0 s", "Aktivator ---" and "Inhibitor ---". I want the "0 s" to stay top right and move the "Aktivator ---" and "Inhibitor ---" to top left.

Comment: Here are other ways to split the key in gnuplot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831102/how-to-split-the-key-in-gnuplot

Comment: @newstudent well, another option, but multiplot is an overkill to what OP wants to achieve here.

Comment: @theozh might be, but it gives more control to split the key in gnuplot. Your answer does work here, but in general using `set label` with pointtypes and linetypes  is tricky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several titles:

- a title of a plot, check `help title`
- a title of a legend/key, check `help key`, option `title`
- a title of a multiplot, check `help multiplot`, option `title`

I guess you want to separate the key title and move it to the other side. I guess that's not possible.
Probably the easiest is to place a label. You place it e.g. at a position relative to the graph (here: 0.95,0.95) and the text alignment at that position is `right`.  Check `help label`.

Labels are persistent (e.g. in a multiplot environment), so don't forget to set `unset label 1` or overwrite it with another title for the next multi(sub)plot.

**Script:**

```
### place a label/title
reset session

set key top left
set label 1 "0 s" at graph 0.95,0.95 font ",12" right

set offsets 0,0,0.2,0.2

plot sin(x), cos(x)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]